# Does Django's models.TextField() provide much security when not used with Django's form validation?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django App that accepts user input in a free text field. In the model I have the following validation rule for the field:

```
body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

If I decide not to validate input in the front end and I don't use Django forms, am I leaving a big gaping security hole, or does models.TextField() provide quite a lot of protection?

For context, I'm sending data via AJAX and in this case I think it would be easier to not use a Django Form, that's very possibly because I don't know Django well enough, but I think the question still stands.

Comment: It all depends on what you do with the data. You should never pass user provided data to the front-end un-escaped, Django templates protect you from this somewhat by escaping everything by default

Comment: Here's a useful post which might help if you decide to use Django forms: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/work-with-ajax-django

Comment: @IainShelvington in the template I have {{ model.body }} - I need to add something like {{ model.body|escape }}? Obviously I'd need to look up the correct way. Just wondering if that's what you're referring to. Do you also mean to say that the model would throw an error rather than save malicious code because of TextField()?